# MySQL map csv fields to specific fields in datatable

Tags: mysql, csv, load

New to SQL, and trying to load in a CSV file into my data table where the columns in the CSV dont match up to the same order in the table. Also there is no PK in the CSV

to illustrate, this is a snippet of my CSV and SQL table

csv1,csv2,csv3,csv4...

sql1(PK),sql2,sql3,sql4,sql5...

the load needs to go like this

```
csv1 -> sql2
csv2 -> sql3
csv3 -> sql4
```

is there any other way apart from using the following to achieve what i want

```
load data local infile 'xxx'
into table tbl_x
fields terminated by ','
lines terminated by '\r\n'
ignore 4 lines
(@csv1,@csv2,@csv3,@csv4)
set 
sql2 = @csv1,
sql3 = @csv2,
sql4 = @csv3;
```

Comment: Is `sql1` an auto increment column?

Comment: yes it is, so it should populate as rows are added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just load your CSV data into a temporary table, and then insert that data into your desired target table.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'xxx'
INTO TABLE tbl_temp
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 4 LINES
```

Then use `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` to populate `tbl_x`:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_x (sql1, sql2, sql3, ...)
SELECT NULL, csv1, csv2, ...
FROM tbl_temp
```

By inserting `NULL` into your primary key column, MySQL should auto increment that column.